# How to detect if the current major mode is derived from prog-mode

Tags: emacs, mode

I want to write a function that invokes one of 2 functions, depending on whether the current major mode is a prog-mode.  How do I detect if the current major mode is a prog-mode?

Answer (score 9):

```
(if (derived-mode-p 'prog-mode) ...)
```

Comment: This does not work if `prog-mode` is `defalias`'d, e.g. `groovy-mode` has `;; For compatibility with Emacs < 24` `(defalias 'groovy-parent-mode (if (fboundp 'prog-mode) 'prog-mode 'fundamental-mode))`, and `(derived-mode-p 'prog-mode)` evaluates to `nil` (my Emacs is 26.x, and the alias is to `prog-mode`). Do you perchance have an idea how to work around this?

Comment: @kkm this is https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=32795 which is fixed in Emacs 27.

Comment: Great, thanks! It did really seem to me like a bug.

Comment: I notice that the current fix inverts things -- `(derived-mode-p 'prog-mode)` will be true, but `(derived-mode-p 'groovy-parent-mode)` no longer will be.  That's a *better* way around, but it would be nice to make them *both* work.

Comment: Hard to tell what can of worms that would open. A mode has at most one parent by definition, and the `groovy-parent-mode` is really an internal package variable (should have been defined with a `--` internal variable convention, like `cmake--parent-mode` mentioned in the bug). One possible unexpected side effect would be a cycle in dependencies introduced by careless aliasing.